Angular Observable keeps displaying an array instead of a string
The project is kindof a mess so I will attempt to be as simple as possible, but for context this is using angular, spring, and maven. I am fairly certain the only relevant part is angular, though.
I am attempting to make a call to display information from a resourcebundle and it works fine with several consol prints showing the string intact along the way, but it still displays as an array on the page when loaded (ex: displays as S,t,r,i,n,g instead of String)
heres the MessageController in java (the multithreading is part of the assignment, I dont believe it to be relevant, but included it for context):
public class MessageController {
    static ExecutorService messageExecutor = newFixedThreadPool(2);
    public static String myMessage = "";
    public static String myMessage1 = "";
    @RequestMapping(path = "/welcome")
    public String welcome(){
        Properties properties=new Properties();
        messageExecutor.execute(()->{
            try{
                InputStream stream = new ClassPathResource("welcome_en.properties").getInputStream();
                properties.load(stream);
                System.out.println(properties.getProperty("welcome"));
                myMessage = properties.getProperty("welcome");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        messageExecutor.execute(()->{
            try{
                InputStream stream = new ClassPathResource("welcome_fr.properties").getInputStream();
                properties.load(stream);
                System.out.println(properties.getProperty("welcome"));
                myMessage1 = properties.getProperty("welcome");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        String arrayMessage = myMessage+ ", " +myMessage1;
        System.out.println(arrayMessage);
        return arrayMessage;
    }
}

At this point everything prints to the console correctly, everything appears fine.
next, in the app.component.ts we have:
ngOnInit(){
      this.getWelcome().subscribe(
        welcome=>{
          this.welcome= <any>Object.values(welcome);
        }}

and getWelcome():
getWelcome(): Observable<any>{
      return this.httpClient.get(this.baseURL + '/welcome', {responseType: "text"});
    }

this is just set with:
welcome!:string;

and called in the html as:
{{welcome}}

using this, the webpage displays:
W,e,l,c,o,m,e,,, ,B,i,e,n,v,e,n,u,e
even though http://localhost:8080/welcome correctly displays:
Welcome, Bienvenue
how do I get this message to display properly?

Why are you using Object.values? If that's called on a string, you'll get the characters as an array.

What should i be using? Object.values is what the instructor used in the example code.

I don't know, because you haven't shown how this.welcome is used, or what it's expected to be. I can guess that you want JSON.parse instead, but I'm not sure.

I think that would just be just "welcome!:string;". is that what you were looking for? I want to make sure im adding the correct info to the question

I have updated the question in hopes that adds what you are looking for

Have you tried this.welcome = welcome; without Object.values()?

When you subscribe to the getWelcome() Observable and cast it to object.values, you are treating it as an object which results in splitting the string into an array of characters.
modify getWelcome() function to parse the response as plain text instead of trying to parse it as JSON
Here's how you can do it:
ngOnInit() {
  this.getWelcome().subscribe(
    welcome => {
      this.welcome = welcome;
    }
  );
}

getWelcome(): Observable<string> {
  return this.httpClient.get(this.baseURL + '/welcome', { responseType: "text" });
}

the welcome property will contain the plain text response from the server and it should display correctly in your HTML template

This works! thank you! I dont know why the sample code had that at all.
as a second point, do you happen to know why this message doesnt load on the very first page load? it only loads the text after a refresh.

Check if there is any delay in the backend

I imagine the multithreading portion introduces a slight latency? How do i account for that?

You are returning arrayMessage synchronously, which means the response will be sent before both properties files are loaded.

I don't know why you try to do:
this.welcome= <any>Object.values(welcome);
Can you try:
ngOnInit(){
      this.getWelcome().subscribe(
        welcome=> {
          this.welcome = welcome;
        }}

And you can add some pipe into like:
// unsubcribeVar is a subject variable in class and do unsubcribe when component destroyed
this.getWelcome().pipe(takeUtil(this.unsubcribeVar)).subcribe((welcome)=>{
    this.welcome = welcome;
});

